# How can I set value to multiple inputs with same name?

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing, nightwatch.js

I have a form that repeats a couple of times on a page, each form has input with say name=firstName, I want to set some value in each.
How can I get a list of those inputs and loop through them so I can do setValue?

Answer (score 0):

```
const names = ["Adam", "Kevin", "Pam"];

browser.elements('css selector', '[name="firstName"]', function(elements) {
  elements.value.forEach(function(elementsObj, index) {
    browser.setValue(elementsObj.ELEMENT, names);
  })
})
```

– `.elements()` searches for multiple elements on the page and returns them as web element JSON objects that can be accessed using `elements.value`

– Now when we have the web elements, we would then apply a forEach loop to iterate over the different elements using `elements.value.forEach(function(elementsObj, index)`

– Now using `setValue` we will set the value from the names array to all the input boxes on the webpage